# momentJS date string add 5 days

Tags: javascript, momentjs, addition, days

i have a start date string "20.03.2014" and i want to add 5 days to this with moment.js but i don't get the new date "25.03.2014" in the alert window.

here my javascript Code:

```
startdate = "20.03.2014";
var new_date = moment(startdate, "DD-MM-YYYY").add("DD-MM-YYYY", 5);

alert(new_date);
```

here my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jbgUt/1/

How can i solve this ?

I like this string format "25.03.2014"

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 524, accepted):

UPDATED: January 19, 2016

As of moment 2.8.4 - use `.add(5, 'd')` (or `.add(5, 'days')`) instead of `.add('d', 5)`

```
var new_date = moment(startdate, "DD-MM-YYYY").add(5, 'days');
```

Thanks @Bala for the information.

UPDATED: March 21, 2014

This is what you'd have to do to get that format.

[Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VtoCorleone/jbgUt/2/)

```
startdate = "20.03.2014";
var new_date = moment(startdate, "DD-MM-YYYY").add('days', 5);

var day = new_date.format('DD');
var month = new_date.format('MM');
var year = new_date.format('YYYY');

alert(day + '.' + month + '.' + year);
```

ORIGINAL: March 20, 2014

You're not telling it how/what unit to add.  Use -

```
 var new_date = moment(startdate, "DD-MM-YYYY").add('days', 5);
```

Comment: i want to see this format "25.03.2014" in the alert window how can i implement this ?

Comment: As of moment-2.8.4, I can see deprecated message with add('days',5). 

Use add(5,'days') instead.

Comment: The correct syntax : moment().add(5, 'days').format("D/M/YYYY")
You can look a while here : https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

Comment: @Bala, Can we use add(1,'day'), if there is only one day to add ?

Comment: @Ashiq, as per docs it should be either 'days' or 'd'. (Although 'day' will work as it starts with d, it should not be used)

Answer (score 35):

```
moment(moment('2015/04/09 16:00:00').add(7, 'd').format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'))
```

has to format and then convert to moment again.

Comment: You saved me lots of minutes : )

Answer (score 29):

You can add days in different formats:

```
// Normal adding
moment().add(7, 'days');

// Short Hand
moment().add(7, 'd');

// Literal Object    
moment().add({days:7, months:1});
```

See more about it on Moment.js docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

Answer (score 27):

The function add() returns the old date, but changes the original date :)

```
startdate = "20.03.2014";
var new_date = moment(startdate, "DD.MM.YYYY");
new_date.add(5, 'days');
alert(new_date);
```

Comment: Yeah that's weird. When checking `moment(startdate).add(5, 'days')` in the console you get `Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "[the original date]",}`, and I was sure the `add` method wasn't working. After spending a  few minutes, I realized the method WAS working, because if you open the object you get `Moment
_d
:
[The date with the addition]
_f
:
"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"
_i
:
[The original date]`... The date has actually changed (you'll get the correct result with `moment(startdate).add(5, 'days').format('YYYYMMDD')`), but it's confusing that it seems the date hasn't changed. :-|

Answer (score 20):

If we want to use the current date or present date:

```
var new_date = moment(moment(), "MM-DD-YYYY").add(7, 'days')
alert(new_date);
```

Answer (score 19):

```
var end_date = moment(start_date).clone().add(5, 'days');
```

Comment: It is the `clone()` that really helps here

Comment: Thanks for saving my day!! `clone()` is really important, since `add()` mutates the original moment as the [doc](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) said.

Answer (score 6):

If you do end up running with formatting problems after adding X time to the function, try this format:

`startDate = moment(startDate).add(1, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD");`

instead of:

`startDate = moment(startDate, "YYYY-MM-DD").add(1, "days");`

This last version keeps the time attached to the returned data, whereas the format method doesn't and literally returns YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 4):

To get an actual working example going that returns what one would expect:

```
var startdate = "20.03.2014";
var new_date = moment(startdate, "DD.MM.YYYY");
var thing = new_date.add(5, 'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
window.console.log(thing)
```

Answer (score 4):

1. add https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js  to your html page
2. `var todayDate = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');//to get today date 06/03/2018 if you want to add extra day to your current date`
   then
3. `var dueDate = moment().add(15,'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY')// to add 15 days to current date..`

point 2 and 3 are using in your jquery code...

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce what they said in a few lines of code:

```
var nowPlusOneDay = moment().add('days', 1);
var nowPlusOneDayStr = nowPlusOneDay.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

alert('nowPlusOneDay Without Format(Unix Date):'+nowPlusOneDay);
alert('nowPlusOneDay Formatted(String):'+nowPlusOneDayStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

updated:

```
startdate = "20.03.2014";
var new_date = moment(startdate, "DD-MM-YYYY").add(5,'days');

alert(new_date)
```