# How to increase the day in this date string '2022-05-06' in JS

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

How to increase the day in this date string '2022-05-06' in JS? It can be both native and moments solution. I checked add method in moment but looks like I am doing something wrong and it doesn't work:

```js
const date = '2022-05-06'
console.log(moment(date).add(1, 'days'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What does it do, what "doesn't work"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547129/momentjs-date-string-add-5-days

Comment: Does this answer your question? [momentJS date string add 5 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547129/momentjs-date-string-add-5-days)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse string to moment object properly:

```js
const date = '2022-05-06'
const newDate = moment(date,'YYYY-MM-DD').add(1, 'days');
```