# Unable to add 5 days to current date using calender

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, react-datepicker, react-calendar

I am trying to pass 2 props to a function, the minDate is to take the current date. The maxDate should take 5 days from today. But the minDate and maxDate are not getting calculated.

```
minDate={moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY')}
maxDate={moment('15/11/2023 22:58:58', 'DD/MM/YYYY').calendar()}
```

Can you please suggest. I am trying to use calendar to adding 5 days using react moment.

Comment: Maybe this can help, please check the below post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22547185/22406515

Answer (score 0):

*moment().add(5, 'days') adds 5 days to the current date, and format('DD-MM-YYYY') is used to format the resulting date in the desired format.*

```
minDate={moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY')}
maxDate={moment().add(5, 'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY')}
```

Comment: This does not work! Already tried

Comment: minDate={moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
            maxDate={moment().add(10, 'days').calendar({ sameElse: 'YYYY-MM-DD' })}
           
This worked, I managed to solve it.

Comment: I ran this code in CodeSandbox and it is working properly.